# Are Vertex Color layers limited to 8?

Tags: vertex-colors

Why is there a limit for vertex-colour layers? Is this a bug or
is there a reason, why I cant add more than 8 vertex-color layers?
I will make a bug-report if it is a bug - but I'm not sure for now.

To see what I'm talking about: Open blender, select the cube then in *`Properties > Data > Vertex Colors Panel`* and add as many layers as possible. It will stop at eight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain limitations are built into the software at the time it is compiled (built) and the number of Vertex Color slots and the number of UV slots (8 in each case) are two such limitations. The software has to be designed with certain assumptions to allow the various data structures to be handled and stored efficiently. At some point in the past it was deemed sufficient to only support 8.

I believe it has been suggested that a future development will increase this limitation - although I can't find reference to it at the moment. For now, I'm afraid 8 is the limit.